# Untitled download occure when I try to download from a local server

Tags: android-studio, android-download-manager, android-networking, download-manager, android-network-security-config

I run an android app that let me download file from an URL, I used download manager to download the files, it works just fine when I use a public URL server from the internet but when I use my local server it doesn't download the file and give me "Untitled download", here's my MainActivity and Androidmanifest files, how can I fix that ?

```
import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button downloadButton1, downloadButton2, downloadButton3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        downloadButton1 = findViewById(R.id.button_download1);
        downloadButton2 = findViewById(R.id.button_download2);
        downloadButton3 = findViewById(R.id.button_download3);

        downloadButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                downloadFile("https://speed.hetzner.de/100MB.bin", "100MB.bin");
            }
        });

        downloadButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                downloadFile("https://192.168.101.2:3000/HI.bin", "HI.bin");
            }
        });

        
    }

    private void downloadFile(String url, String fileName) {
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES, fileName);
        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
        DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        downloadManager.enqueue(request);
    }
}
type here



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.3downloads"
        tools:targetApi="33"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```